# Mailchimp RSS split by category

Tags: rss, mailchimp

I'd like to build a newsletter with MailChimp that look like HackerNewsletter.
My content is in AirTable, so I can code one (or many) RSS feed.

I wondering how I can display an RSS block in mailchimp filtered on a given rss category ? So I would be able to set N block (one for each category)

```
My Category 1
(If RSSITEM is in "My Category 1" THEN)
*|RSSITEMS:|*
*|RSSITEM:TITLE|* *|RSSITEM:CATEGORIES|*
*|END:RSSITEMS|*
```

Or is there a trick to call multiple RSS feed in multiple block for one newsletter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create N block element filtered on an explicit category. 
Replace RSSBLOCK with FEEDBLOCK to allow custom filter like $category

```
<h4 class="null">#<span style="color:#ff3300"><strong>LIFEHACKER</strong></span></h4>

<hr size="1" style="border-color: #eee;" />*|FEEDBLOCK:https://bot.sarah.encausse.net/rss|*
<ul>
*|FEEDITEMS:[$category=LifeHack]|*
    <li><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*" target="_blank">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</a></li>
*|END:FEEDITEMS|*
</ul>
*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
```

The closest explanation can be found in MergeTag: https://mailchimp.com/en/help/add-a-blog-post-to-any-campaign/